# how to automatically update head description of a source file with Apache ant?

Tags: ant

Is there an ant task to update head description of a source file automatically? For example, the head description on license, copyright, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use some keyword mechanism from your versioning tool, f.e. [cvs keywords](http://badgertronics.com/writings/cvs/keywords.html)
- other tools may have a similar feature - or filter task, [see Ant manual filter task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/filter.html)